# Interstitial ads in audio app

Tags: admob

What is the best way to integrated Interstitial ads in audio app .
at first I put ads after 50 sec from music beginning, but i've received email from Admob"This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a result, ad serving has been disabled to your application."
"
Violation explanation
LAYOUT ENCOURAGES ACCIDENTAL CLICKS - INTERSTITIAL ADS: Publishers are not permitted to encourage users to click AdMob interstitial ads in any way. This includes any implementation that may encourage accidental clicks, such as placing an interstitial ad in a way that prevents viewing the app’s core content or placing an interstitial ad in a way that interferes with navigating or interacting with the app’s core content and functionality."

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: no one can answer me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAYOUT ENCOURAGES ACCIDENTAL CLICKS - INTERSTITIAL ADS means you're showing ads at places that causes users to clicks them inadvertently. It isn't about playing music/sound in your app but rather non-compliant implementations that include:

> Interstitial ads that appear before the app has opened or after the app has closed.
>
> Interstitial ads that are triggered after a user closes another interstitial ad.
>
> Interstitial ads loading unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content.
>
> Remember to only serve interstitials between pages of content.
>
> Interstitial ads that trigger after every user click.
>
> Interstitial ads that appear during periods of game play or heavy user interaction.

Check the [official disallowed interstitial implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287) for more.

Once you fix the issue, you can update your app and appeal for ad-serving to be re-enabled

Comment: so if i put Interstitial ads in Mediaplayer after user choosing the song it's ok ??

Comment: How does one " appeal for ad-serving to be re-enabled"?

Comment: @RSH1 Use this form https://support.google.com/admob/contact/appeal_policy_violation?rd=1

Comment: @ZainaDahan  can I put an ad when the audio has over or I say the audio has ended playing, is it allowed