# How to fix "Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks - Interstitial Ads" warning by admob in android?

Tags: android, admob

I've integrated Interstitial Ads in my app. Below are the transition,

```
         - Screen 3 

         - Screen 4 

         - Screen 5 

         - Screen 6 

Screen 2 - Screen 7 

         - Screen 8 

         - Screen 9 

         - Screen 10 

         - Screen 11 

         - Screen 12
```

While the transition happens from Screen 2 to Screen n (Where n is 3-12), an interstitial ad is called. I hope this is allowed to do.

Today, I have received a mail from Admob saying that Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks. How do I fix this? I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Below is the code of one of the activities.

```
public class CC extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {
ConnectivityReceiver conn;

CheckingStatus checkingStatus;

private static final String TAG = "CC";
private AdView mAdView;

InterstitialAd interstitial;

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-4189677300abcdefgh.....";
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    checkingStatus=new CheckingStatus();
    conn=new ConnectivityReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(conn, intentFilter);
    checkfunction(CC.this);

    setContentView(R.layout.cc);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CC");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//for banner ads
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        findViewById(R.id.cc1).setOnClickListener(listener_ca);
        findViewById(R.id.cc2).setOnClickListener(listener_cb);
        findViewById(R.id.cc3).setOnClickListener(listener_ccc);


//for interstitial ads
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest aDRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitialAd.loadAd(aDRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

        }
    });


};

View.OnClickListener listener_ca = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CC.this, pt_ca.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

View.OnClickListener listener_cb = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CC.this, pt_cb.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

View.OnClickListener listener_ccc = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CC.this, pt_ccc.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

public void checkfunction(Context context){
    boolean isConnected=ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
    checkingStatus.notification(isConnected,context);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    checkfunction(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    return true;
}
}
```

What changes should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062114/layout-encourages-accidental-clicks-interstitial-ads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interstitial ads in audio app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849558/interstitial-ads-in-audio-app)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420728/layout-encourages-accidental-clicks-interstitial-ads-admob?rq=1

Comment: @NileshRathod, It might look like the duplicate of those questions but I am unable to understand what went wrong here. Can you please enlighten me with whats the possible way to fix it as I am unable to understand the other situations mentioned in the above comment sections?

Comment: `if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }` must be call immediately when you are transition from one activity to another not whenever the ad is loaded.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar is there a way to load the ad well before and display it when the transition takes place?

Comment: Yes you can pre-load the ad.

Comment: May I know how to pre load it, are there any leads for the same? @MuhammadBabar

Comment: Like this `interstitialAd.loadAd(aDRequest);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What went wrong is the ad placement. Basically you pop up an interstitial while the user is transitioning forward from one screen to another with intent to do some action there, resulting in accidental clicks.

What you can do is place the interstitial ad while the user is in backward transition, i.e. on the click of back button. In the`OnBackPress`method of your desired activity. That should fix your issue.

For more check on google ad policies you can go through this [page](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287)

Comment: Never knew about this. Much Thanks @KshitijJaju!
Will look into that.

Comment: But in the same link that you have posted, it says that it can be placed between transitions. Check this image https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/91E0E29ADFA1A1BF42097E0699CC491BE874

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the next code

```
import {InterstitialAd, AdEventType} from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';



const adUnitId = 'ca-app-pub-0000000000000000/0000000000';
const [loadingAds, setLoadingAds] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
  let interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
    requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
    keywords: ['game', 'education', 'learning', 'kids', 'smart'],
  });
  if (interstitial != undefined) {
    setLoadingAds(true);
  }
  interstitial.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.LOADED, () => {
    //Ready to show 
    interstitial.show();
    setLoadingAds(false);
  });
  interstitial.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.ERROR, (error) => {
    console.log('Ad error:', error);
    setLoadingAds(false);
  });
  interstitial.load();

  return () => {
    interstitial = null;
    setLoadingAds(false);
  };
}, []);
```

You can read the documentation about `react-native-google-mobile-ads` [here](https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/displaying-ads)